# Using Maybe and Writer together

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Here is my egg packing factory:

```
type Eggs = Int
data Carton = Carton Eggs deriving Show

add :: Eggs -> Carton -> Maybe Carton
add e (Carton c)
    | c + e <= 12 = Just (Carton $ c + e)
    | otherwise = Nothing

main = do
    print $ pure(Carton 2) >>= add 4 >>= add 4 >>= add 3
```

Seems to work well, I can nicely chain `add` functions.

But I want to record a log of how many eggs were added at every step. So I do this:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer

type Eggs = Int
data Carton = Carton Eggs deriving Show

add :: Eggs -> Carton -> Writer [String] (Maybe Carton)
add e (Carton c)
    | c + e <= 12 = do
        tell ["adding " ++ show e]
        return (Just (Carton $ c + e))
    | otherwise = do
        tell ["cannot add " ++ show e]
        return Nothing

main = do
    let c = add 4 $ Carton 2
    print $ fst $ runWriter c
    mapM_ putStrLn $ snd $ runWriter c
```

This gives me what I want: I can see the resulting carton and the record for 4 eggs being added.

But I seem to have lost the ability to chain `add` functions like I did before:

```
let c = pure(Carton 2) >>= add 4 -- works
let c = pure(Carton 2) >>= add 4 >>= add 2 -- does not work
```

How can I chain my new writer-enabled `add` functions? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Note that writing it as `add 4 >=> add 2 $ Carton 2` or `add 2 <=< add 4 $ Carton 2` or, using the less common &, `Carton 2 & add 4 >=> add 2` allows you to leave out the pure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, the second `>>=` in the expression is for the `Monad` instance of `Maybe` while in the second example it is from the `Monad` instance of `Writer`. Specifically, in the first example the `>>=` expects a function with type `Carton -> Maybe Carton`, like `add 2`, while in the second example `>>=` expects a function of type `Maybe Carton -> Writer [String] (Maybe Carton)`. In both examples `pure (Carton 2)`>>=`add 4` works because `pure (Carton 2)` has type `Maybe Carton` and `add 4` has type `Carton -> <something>`, so you have no problems. Adding another `>>=` to the expression triggers the error because in the first example this `>>=` has the same type of the first one while in the second example it isn't the same `>>=`. A solution can be to change `add` such that it has type `Eggs -> Maybe Carton -> Writer [String] (Maybe Carton)`:

```
add :: Eggs -> Maybe Carton -> Writer [String] (Maybe Carton)
add e Nothing = return Nothing
add e (Just (Carton c))
    | c + e <= 12 = do
        tell ["adding " ++ show e]
        return (Just (Carton $ c + e))
    | otherwise = do
        tell ["cannot add " ++ show e]
        return Nothing
```

note that this means that you cannot use anymore `pure (Carton 2)` but you need `pure (Just $ Carton 2)`:

```
 > pure (Just $ Carton 2) >>= add 2 >>= add 5
 WriterT (Identity (Just (Carton 9),["adding 2","adding 5"]))
```

Said that, I would suggest you to use [monad transformers](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html) to compose `Maybe` and `Writer` because this in a common use case for them. Your example could be rewritten as

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import Control.Monad.Writer

type Eggs = Int
data Carton = Carton Eggs deriving Show

add :: Eggs -> Carton -> MaybeT (Writer [String]) Carton
add e (Carton c)
    | c + e <= 12 = do
        lift $ tell ["adding " ++ show e]
        return (Carton $ c + e)
    | otherwise = do
        lift $ tell ["cannot add " ++ show e]
        mzero

main = do
    let c = return (Carton 2) >>= add 4 >>= add 2
    let result = runWriter $ runMaybeT c
    print $ fst $ result
    mapM_ putStrLn $ snd $ result
```

A few things have changed from your example:

1. `MaybeT m a` is the monad transformer. In this example, `m` is `Writer [String]` and `a` is `Carton`. To run everything we first `runMaybeT`, which gives you a `Writer [String] (Maybe Carton)`, and then we call `runWriter` on it like you have done in your example.
2. To use `Writer` functions in `MaybeT (Writer [String])` we need to `lift` them. For instance `lift $ tell ["something"]`
3. `return carton` is used to return a `Just Carton` while `mzero` is used to return `Nothing`

One last thing: in this example we cannot compose `Maybe` and `Writer` the other way around, with `WriterT [String] Maybe Carton`, because when there are more than 12 eggs `runWriterT` would return `Nothing` and suppress the history:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer

type Eggs = Int
data Carton = Carton Eggs deriving Show

add :: Eggs -> Carton -> WriterT [String] Maybe Carton
add e (Carton c)
    | c + e <= 12 = do
        tell ["adding " ++ show e]
        lift $ Just $ Carton $ c + e
    | otherwise = do
        tell ["cannot add " ++ show e]
        lift Nothing

main = do
    let c = return (Carton 2) >>= add 4 >>= add 20
    case runWriterT c of
      Nothing ->
        print "nothing to print"
      Just (carton, history) -> do
        print carton
        mapM_ putStrLn $ history
```

Comment: This is the exact answer I was expecting. Would you be able to give an example using monad transformers?

Comment: Excellent example. Thank you very much for that. I do seem to be able to run your `MaybeT (Writer [String]) Carton` example without `lift`.

Comment: `tell` works on a more generic version of `Writer` called [`MonadWriter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Writer-Class.html). `MaybeT` has an instance of `MonadWriter` which means that you can use `tell` directly for `MaybeT` instead of `lift`ing the `Writer` version. Within the instance itself, [`tell` is defined as `lift . tell`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/src/Control-Monad-Writer-Class.html#line-151), which is what I was using here. I think the explicit composition helps to understand the example.

Answer (score 6):

Just compose `add` with `MaybeT`:

```
import Control.Trans.Monad.Maybe

test = pure (Carton 2) >>= MaybeT . add 3
                       >>= MaybeT . add 4
                       >>= MaybeT . add 5

runTest = do
  print $ fst $ runWriter (runMaybeT test)
```

Full example at: http://lpaste.net/169070

Answer (score 5):

I'd change `add` &c to use `MaybeT (Writer [String])`:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

type Eggs = Int
data Carton = Carton Eggs deriving Show

main = do
    let c = add 4 $ Carton 2
        (result, log) = runWriter $ runMaybeT c
    print result
    mapM_ putStrLn log

add :: Eggs -> Carton -> MaybeT (Writer [String]) Carton
add e (Carton c)
    | c + e <= 12 = do
          tell ["adding " ++ show e]
          return $ Carton $ c + e
    | otherwise = do
          tell ["cannot add " ++ show e]
          mzero
```

this will allow your original code of

```
pure (Carton 2) >>= add 4 >>= add 2
```

to work as expected.